# How to detect image which has blocking(pixelated) artifact by opencv?

Tags: opencv, video, video-capture

I captured frames from music video with openCV(python), but some of frames showed pixelated artifact(i.e. like image below).
[image]
 I want to remove this bad quality image from list of capture, but I don't have idea how to detect this bad quality image.

I want to know that way to find image has pixelated artifact by using openCV.

Comment: check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418983/how-to-detect-if-an-image-is-pixelated?rq=1